# ¿Para que es la funcion zip en python?

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy haciendo ejercicios de POO con python y checkeando codigo me encontre con esta zip()

```
class pedido:
def __init__(self,productos,cantidades):
    self.__productos = productos
    self.__cantidades = cantidades

def total_pedido(self):
    total = 0

    for(p,c) in zip(self.__productos,self.__cantidades):
        total = total + p.calcular_Total(c)
```

aqui el metodo que muestra los datos

```
def mostrar_pedido(self):
    for(p,c) in zip(self.__productos,self.__cantidades):
        print("producto",p.nombre,"cantidad"+str(c))"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que hace la funcion `zip()` es "empaquetar" los contenidos de se encuentren entre paréntesis, si te das cuenta esta pasando dos parametros, esto es bastante util para hacer codigo mas optimo y limpio y para evitar funciones rebuscadas

```
for(p,c) in zip(self.__productos,self.__cantidades):
        total = total + p.calcular_Total(c)
```

Si analizamos ese pedazo de codigo tenemos que la variable `p` es correspondiente a `self.__productos` mientras que la variable `c` es correspondiente a `self.__cantidades` dicho de otra manera, te deja iterar sobre los dos objetos a la par.

Puedes encontrar mas información en [Python zip() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp#:~:text=The%20zip()%20function%20returns,iterator%20are%20paired%20together%20etc.)

Comment: gracias por tu amabilidad